# elasticsearch python client set size to 0 for aggregation

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I want to run query using python elasticsearch client

```
GET /employee-index/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": { "field": "gender.keyword" }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I am doing but it is returning me the records

```
es = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=es, index="employee-index").aggs.bucket('gender', 'terms', field='gender.keyword')
s = s.execute()
print (s)
```

It I look at the query running to ES it only has aggs count.
I couldn't find in the documentation how to set size to 0 for returning only the aggregation.
I try setting but it doesn't work.

```
Search(using=es, index="employee-index").aggs.bucket('gender', 'terms', field='gender.keyword', size=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **s[0]** to have the aggregation count only:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=es, index="employee-index")
s = s[0]
s.aggs.bucket('gender', 'terms', field='gender.keyword')
hits = s.execute()

print(hits)
```